# Is there a way to see the radar info ATC has?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-tracking

I want to track GA helicopter traffic coming and going from NYC. I know that most routes the helicopters fly require them to pick up a transponder code from ATC, which means they are in the system.

Is there a public feed of that ATC data?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, As far as I understand, sites like flightradar24.com and flightaware.com only track aircraft transmitting ADS-B out or with Mode-S transponders. I'm interested in tracking aircraft with Mode-C transponders that have picked up a unique transponder code in order to enter the class B.

Comment: No there's not, but you can use services such as https://www.flightradar24.com/

Comment: As far as I understand, sites like flightradar24.com and flightaware.com only track aircraft transmitting ADS-B out or with Mode-S transponders. I'm interested in tracking aircraft with Mode-C transponders that have picked up a unique transponder code.

Comment: You can't track a Mode-C transponder since it doesn't broadcast location data with the interrogation. All you get with Mode-C is the squawk code and altitude.

Comment: An old-school method would be to monitor the frequency(ies) used in the airspace you're interested in via a handheld radio.

Comment: I'm already doing that, but was trying to find an automated way of tracking specific flights for business reasons.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, you CAN track Mode-C transponder but multiple receivers are needed and the position is calculated by comparing time delays between receivers - see: Multilateration

Comment: See [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13335/8730) as to why helicopters don't show in flightradar24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in or around NYC, flightradar24 will give you most, but not all, traffic including helos and ATC radar traffic.

flightradar24 most likely has several ADS-B receivers in that area that not only catch aircraft transponder/UAT output, but they also catch FAA ADS-B ground station broadcasts. The ground station will broadcast any known traffic (mode C radar traffic included) that ATC is aware of to any client aircraft that are in the area that have their ADS-B output configured to inform the ground station that they are capable of displaying traffic data. Most private GA aircraft with ADS-B are configured this way because there are iPad apps that will display it while airborne. The ground station will broadcast that traffic and a local flightradar24 receiver gets it too and up it goes on the website. The data may be limited to just aircraft in the vicinity of the client aircraft but in an area like NYC, there are typically many GA aircraft (clients) out there at any time that are configured as ADS-B in capable.